# Session not saving in Elixir Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm making a signin controller.

I set the session as such:

```
conn = put_session(conn, :user_id, user.id)
IEx.pry
redirect conn, to: account_path(conn, :show)
```

It looks set as on the pry line when I print the conn I get

```
...
:plug_session => %{"user_id" => 6}, :plug_session_fetch => :done,
...
```

Then in the next controller which we redirect to we get

```
get_session(conn, :user_id) => nil
```

The 302 from the signin controller seems to set a session cookie as the response includes

```
set-cookie:_rebirth_key=g3QAAAABbQAAAAd1c2VyX2lkYQY=--KJ9iow5QUIqw1ggyPla--EGp-dY=; path=/; HttpOnly
```

How do I make the session persist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but I think `fetch_session` might not be the right function to get the value from the session. Try

```
get_session(conn, :user_id)
```

instead.

Comment: To elaborate. `put_session` adds a specified value for a key, `get_session` will return that value by its key. Source: [get_session docs](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#get_session/2). `fetch_session` fetches session from the session store or cookie.

Comment: My bad, I used get_session, weird typo. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

To people who might run into the same problem I did; make sure you're not calling `configure_session(drop: true)` unless you really want to.

If, in an attempt to enforce a fresh session (like if a user just logged in) and you call `conn |> configure_session(drop: true) |> clear_session |> put_session(:key, value)`, your session will be empty.